# comparing two values in GotoIf() application

Tags: asterisk

whats wrong with the following statement.

```
 exten => _xxx,n,GotoIf($[${countApp} > 1]?yes,1:not,1)
```

error given is.

[Feb 22 00:51:25] WARNING[1561]: ast_expr2.fl:468 ast_yyerror: ast_yyerror():  syntax error:
syntax error, unexpected '>', expecting $end; Input: > 1
                                                     ^

how can i fix this problem,thanks

Answer (score 0):

That usually happens when the variable (`${countApp}` in this case) is blank/not set